# Need to end a while loop when answer is correct

Tags: java, while-loop

I have got this program working where a number is entered and if it is to big (over 100) it ask them to re enter a number. My problem is when they enter a correct number it says number to big enter a new number. Please help:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class roomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr =  new Scanner (System.in);
        int num = 0;

        System.out.print("Input a number between 1 - 75 please");
        num = scnr.nextInt();

        while (num < 100){
            System.out.print(num);
            System.out.print(" ");
            num = num + 2;

        }


    System.out.println("Number is to high, please choose again");

main(args);


    }

}
```

Input a number between 1 - 75 please **200**
Number is to high, please choose again
Input a number between 1 - 75 please **55**
55 57 59 61 63 65 67 69 71 73 75 77 79 81 83 85 87 89 91 93 95 97 99 Number is to high, please choose again
Input a number between 1 - 75 please

How do I get it to stop once the correct answer it outputted.

Comment: You also have an infinite recursion for some reason...

Comment: You'll have to go back the basic docs to look up recursion. Look at the example it there. You'll notice a couple of errors.

Comment: Why is there "Input a number between 1 - 75 please"? Shouldn't this be 100?